# Custom keyboard in iphone

Tags: ios, xcode, swift-extensions

Does any one know how to Create custom keyboard in iphone? Pls give me any samples for custom keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Hi you need to try following link. They have explained very well and step by step that **how to create Custom Keyboard**. http://www.appdesignvault.com/ios-8-custom-keyboard-extension/

But while creating **Custom Keyboard** there are some **limitations** you must know:

1. A Custom Keyboard cannot be used to type into certain text input objects. These include the secure text input objects (any object that has its secureText property set to YES) and phone pad objects (any object that has a keyboard type trait of UIKeyboardTypePhonePad or UIKeyboardTypeNamePhonePad). When the user types in any of these text input objects, the system temporarily replaces your custom keyboard with the system keyboard, and on typing in a non-secure or non-phone pad object, your keyboard resumes.
2. Input dictation isn’t possible for a custom keyboard since, like all extensions in iOS 8, it has no access to the device microphone.
3. Selecting text is also not possible. Text selection is under the control of the app that is using the keyboard.
4. Closely related to the above point, editing menu options i.e. Cut, Copy, Paste are inaccessible. If an app provides an editing menu interface, the keyboard has no access to it.
5. App developers can reject the use of custom keyboards in their app. This can especially be done in apps that are sensitive to security such as banking apps.
6. You cannot display key artwork above the top edge of a custom keyboard’s primary view the same way Apple does when you tap and hold a key in the top view.

and very **Important** you must follow the **Apple Extensions guide** 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH16-SW1

Enjoy. Happy coding.!!!